# Finding the image of a line or circle under a Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, mobius-transformation

Consider an extended Möbius transformation $f : \hat{\mathbb C} \to \hat{\mathbb C}$ where $\hat{\mathbb C} = \mathbb C \, \cup \, \{\infty\}$ such that

$f(z) := \begin{cases} \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \iff z \in \mathbb C \, \backslash \{ -\frac{d}c\} \\ \infty \iff z = -\frac{d}c \\ \frac{a}c \iff z = \infty\end{cases}$

where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb C$ so that $f$ is bijective. Let's restrict the domain to either a line or a circle in $\mathbb C$.

As known, every line or circle in $\mathbb C$ maps to a line or circle in $\mathbb C$ under $f$. To find what the image is, consider we evaluate $f$ at $z = z_0, z_1, z_2$ where $z_0, z_1, z_2$ are different complex numbers in the domain (as $f$ is bijective, we know that $z_0, z_1, z_2$ will map to different points as well). Define $x_k := \mathcal{Re}(z_k)$ and $y_k := \mathcal{Im}(z_k)$ We can test if

$\begin{cases}\alpha x_0 + \beta y_0 = \gamma \\ \alpha x_1 + \beta y_1 = \gamma \\ \alpha x_2 + \beta y_2 = \gamma \\ \end{cases}$

has any (non-trivial) solution. If not, we know that the image is a circle and we instead get to solve

$\begin{cases} (x_0 - \alpha)^2 + (y_0 - \beta)^2 = \gamma^2 \\ (x_1 - \alpha)^2 + (y_1 - \beta)^2 = \gamma^2 \\ (x_2 - \alpha)^2 + (y_2 - \beta)^2 = \gamma^2\end{cases}$

which has the general solution

$\begin{cases} \alpha = \frac{x_0^2 \left(-y_1\right)+x_0^2 y_2+x_1^2 y_0-x_2^2 y_0+x_2^2 y_1-x_1^2 y_2+y_0 y_1^2-y_0 y_2^2+y_1 y_2^2-y_0^2 y_1+y_0^2 y_2-y_1^2 y_2}{2 \left(x_1 y_0-x_2 y_0-x_0 y_1+x_2 y_1+x_0 y_2-x_1 y_2\right)} \\ \beta = \frac{-x_0 y_1^2+x_0 y_2^2+x_1 y_0^2-x_2 y_0^2+x_2 y_1^2-x_1 y_2^2+x_1 x_0^2-x_2 x_0^2-x_1^2 x_0+x_2^2 x_0-x_1 x_2^2+x_1^2 x_2}{2 \left(x_1 y_0-x_2 y_0-x_0 y_1+x_2 y_1+x_0 y_2-x_1 y_2\right)} \\ \gamma = i \frac{\sqrt{x_1^2-2 x_2 x_1+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2-2 y_1 y_2} \sqrt{2 x_0^2 y_0^2+x_0^2 y_1^2+x_0^2 y_2^2-2 x_0^2 y_0 y_1-2 x_0^2 y_0 y_2-2 x_1 x_0 y_0^2-2 x_2 x_0 y_0^2-2 x_2 x_0 y_1^2-2 x_1 x_0 y_2^2+4 x_2 x_0 y_0 y_1+4 x_1 x_0 y_0 y_2+x_1^2 y_0^2+x_2^2 y_0^2+x_2^2 y_1^2+x_1^2 y_2^2-2 x_2^2 y_0 y_1-2 x_1^2 y_0 y_2+x_0^4-2 x_1 x_0^3-2 x_2 x_0^3+x_1^2 x_0^2+x_2^2 x_0^2+4 x_1 x_2 x_0^2-2 x_1 x_2^2 x_0-2 x_1^2 x_2 x_0+x_1^2 x_2^2+y_0^4+y_0^2 y_1^2+y_0^2 y_2^2+y_1^2 y_2^2-2 y_0 y_1 y_2^2-2 y_0^3 y_1-2 y_0^3 y_2-2 y_0 y_1^2 y_2+4 y_0^2 y_1 y_2}}{\sqrt{-4 x_0^2 y_1^2-4 x_0^2 y_2^2+8 x_0^2 y_1 y_2+8 x_2 x_0 y_1^2+8 x_1 x_0 y_2^2+8 x_1 x_0 y_0 y_1-8 x_2 x_0 y_0 y_1-8 x_1 x_0 y_0 y_2+8 x_2 x_0 y_0 y_2-8 x_1 x_0 y_1 y_2-8 x_2 x_0 y_1 y_2-4 x_1^2 y_0^2-4 x_2^2 y_0^2+8 x_1 x_2 y_0^2-4 x_2^2 y_1^2-4 x_1^2 y_2^2+8 x_2^2 y_0 y_1-8 x_1 x_2 y_0 y_1+8 x_1^2 y_0 y_2-8 x_1 x_2 y_0 y_2+8 x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2}}
\end{cases}$

As you see, this is not something you want to do by hand. Is there any more profound way to see what the image is?

Comment: I don't agree with your statement "To find what the image is, consider we take evaluate $f$ at $z = z_0, z_1, z_2$ where $z_0, z_1, z_2$ are different complex numbers in the domain...". There is almost always a much easier way to determine the image of a locus under this type of transformation...

Comment: @DavidQuinn Could you clarify what you mean? Three points unique define a line or circle, and the question is about finding the explicit equation for this line or circle in $\mathbb C$. The problem is that the  general solution to the non-linear system of equations is not something you want to do by hand, so I'm asking if there is any better method to determine the equation of the image (which is either line or circle in $\mathbb C$).

Comment: Do you wish to determine whether the image of a particular object (line or circle) is a line or a circle, or do you wish to determine the image of the given object? Regardless of the situation, there are easier ways to do what you want.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I would like to know both, actually. That is, whether the image is a line or a circle, and an explicit equation for the image.

Comment: Domain? You mean image, right?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Right, sorry.

Comment: I mean don't bother with the "general solution" or the image of three points, just find the image

Comment: @DavidQuinn Right, I can do that. Say that I get the real part $\frac{2 x (x+1)}{x^2+2 x+2}$ and the imaginary part $\frac{4x}{2x^2 +4x +4}$, how do I know the radius of the circle and its midpoint?

Comment: @MarkusKlyver...where are these expressions coming from? What was the original question in this case?

Comment: @DavidQuinn The original question asked to sketch the image of a Möbius transformation in the $w$-plane, in this case $f(z) = .\frac{2z}{2+z}$, for some lines and circles in $\mathbb C$. The expression above is the real and imaginary part of the image where the domain is the line $x = y$ and $z = x+iy$. Parametrically plot the real and imaginary part in $\mathbb R^2$ for some values of $x$ reveals a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the particular example you have given in your comments, and to illustrate the approach you could take, without using the general solution or considering the image of three particular points, you have $$w=\frac {2z}{2+z}\implies z=\frac{2w}{2-w}=\frac{(2u+2iv)(2-u+iv)}{(2-u-iv)(2-u+iv)}$$

Hence $$x+iy=\frac{(4u-2u^2-2v^2)+i(4v)}{(2-u)^2+v^2}$$

So the image of the line $x=y$ is the circle $$u^2+v^2-2u+2v=0$$

Comment: Maybe you could collaborate a bit more on this; how does $z = \frac{(4u-2u^2-2v^2)+i(4v)}{(2-u)^2+v^2}$ imply that the range satisfies $u^2+v^2-2u+2v=0$?

Comment: ...from the given conditions that $x=y$ as stated by you

Comment: I don't see how. $x = y$ implies $x+xi= \frac{(4u-2u^2-2v^2)+i(4v)}{(2-u)^2+v^2}$, but I don't see how your equation for the range follows.

Comment: By equating real and imaginary parts

Comment: Thank you, that method will work for any line in $\mathbb C$. If the domain is a circle, is there any similar method I can use?

Comment: If your circle is $|z-c|=r$ substitute for $z$ and simplify

Answer (score 6):

For a first overview,

- a line/circle maps to a line iff its image contains $\infty$, i.e., if the origial object contains $-\frac dc$.
- if the original is a line, the image will pass through $\frac ac$
- points closer to $-\frac dc$ are mapped to points further from $\frac ac$

This suggests the following method

- A line that passes through $-\frac dc$ maps to a line through $\frac ac$. Lines are easy, just pick another point (not $-\frac dc$, not $\infty$) and see where it maps; or find the direction via the differential
- A line that does not pass through $-\frac dc$ maps to a circle through $\frac ac$. Find the point on the line that is closest to $-\frac dc$; its image will be furthest from $\frac ac$, i.e., these two points form a diameter - their midpoint is the center of the circle
- A circle through $-\frac dc$ will map to a line. Find the point opposite to $-\frac dc$ and map it. The line through its image and perpendicular to the direction to $\frac ac$ is our image line
- A circle not through $-\frac dc$ will map to a circle. The line through  $-\frac dc$ and the midpoint intersects the circle in two points. Their image is a diameter of the image circle.

Comment: Thank you for this precise summary!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f$ is an automorphism on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$, and  in particular it is bijective. Check that when $c=0$, $f(\infty)=\infty$ and when $c\neq 0$ we have $f(-d/c)=\infty$.

Straight lines always contain the point an infinity, and classic circles never do. Hence, to determine whether an object (line or circle) is mapped to a line or a circle, it suffices to determine for each case $(c=0$ and $c\neq0)$ whether the corresponding preimage of infinity belongs to the object.

Now that you know what your image looks like, just take a few distinct point in the object (two if your image is a line, three if it's a circle), determine their image under $f$, and plug them into the corresponding equation for line/circle to obtain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a circle in $\mathbb{C}$ has a simple form which is expressed just using complex variables, namely $|z-p|^2 = t$ where $p$ is the center and $t$ is the squared radius which is positive. Using properties of the complex conjugate this has the alternate form $z \bar z - \bar p z - p \bar z + p \bar p = t$.

The equation of a line in $\mathbb{C}$ has a similarly simple form.

Use these forms, substitute $z=f^{-1}(w)$ which is a fractional linear transformation, and rearrange terms to get a $w$ equation in one of the same two forms.